# ¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso?

Tags: c++, vscode

no me deja depurar este archivo y no se el motivo, cada que doy f5, me aparece ese mismo error (estoy utilizando visual studio code).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: trata de compilarlo antes de debugear

Comment: mejor instala visual studio ide y seleccionas desarrollo con c++ hay muchos videos para eso en yt